# What's with the prominently placed ads for each question in ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, advertising

For the past couple of days, I've been noticing that serverfault has very prominently placed ads for each question, which doesn't seem to be present in SO.

I don't usually mind the ads on the side in SO because it's not too prominent, and most of the time is relevant. But this serverfault ads are really nagging me.

I thought Jeff was all for [discreet relevant ads](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000893.html) that don't detract the user from his experience. What's happening?

Answer (score 6):

It's reputation-based.  Your serverfault rep is <200, and users with lower rep see more ads.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/

Comment: Beat me too it. Reps are 101 on SF and 1057 on SO.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case but I didn't bother to check the reps.

Comment: That's a rather strange decision isn't it? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/responsible-advertising-feed-a-programmer/

Comment: So that people that are invested in the site are rewarded by not seeing so many ads.

Comment: More likely, frequent users to the site are unlikely to click on the ads directly anyway- they know where to look in the layout for the content they need and won't even see them.

Comment: It's a great way to put off the new users and stifle the expansion of the server fault community...

Answer (score 3):

Could I give some of my reputation from StackOverflow to ServerFault or Superuser up to the limit of getting over the advertising minimum?

Otherwise I'll have to start filtering it.

I'm unlikely to earn enough points, I've been at ~100 for a month now.

Comment: Could I please spend reputation on not seeing any ads anywhere on the trilogy sites?

Comment: Precisely?               ?